# Bernoulli Map: $f'(x) = 2$ Almost Everywhere and "Local Separation" Increases as $2^n$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

The Bernoulli map is

$$x_{n + 1} = f(x_n)=
\begin{cases}
 2x_n, & 0 \leq x_n < 0.5\\
 2x_n - 1, & 0.5 \le x_n \le 1
\end{cases}$$

I am told that (1) $f'(x) = 2$ almost everywhere and so (2) local separation increases as $2^n$.

1. With regards to (1), why is $f'(x) = 2$ **almost everywhere** instead of just everywhere?
2. And what is meant with by (2)? I can't find any information about what "local separation" means in this context.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's calculate $f'(0.5)$:
$$\begin{align}
f'(0.5)&=\lim_\limits{h \to 0} \frac{f(0.5+h)-f(0.5)}{h}\\
&=\lim_\limits{h \to 0} \frac{f(0.5+h)-0}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(0.5+h)}{h}
\end{align}$$
But this limit does not exists, because
$$\begin{align}\lim_{h \to 0+0} \frac{f(0.5+h)}{h}&=\lim_{h \to 0+0} \frac{2(0.5+h)-1}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0+0} \frac{1+2h-1}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0+0} \frac{2h}{h}\\
&=2
\end{align}$$
But
$$\begin{align}\lim_{h \to 0-0} \frac{f(0.5+h)}{h}&=\lim_{h \to 0-0} \frac{2(0.5+h)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0-0} \frac{1+2h}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0-0} \frac{2h}{h}+\frac{1}{h}
\end{align}$$
Which is not finite, but $f'(x)=2 \forall x \in (0, 1) \setminus\{0.5\}$

Comment: Ahh, so the Bernoulli map is not differentiable at $0.5$? I shouldn't have edited my post, then. Thanks for that! Also, any idea about (2)?

Comment: @ThePointer Honestly, I don't know what does the local separation mean. I didn't learn about chaos theory, I just saw that $f'(0.5)$ does not exists :)

Comment: Haha, sounds good enough to me. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @ThePointer You're welcome. But I think you should not just accept my answer because I could not answer your second question :)

Comment: I'll wait for a bit before I accept it. I can't find any reference to "local separation" in chaos theory literature, so I'm guessing it might be language idiosyncratic to the author.

Comment: Since you and Julián Aguirre both answered one part each, and I can only accept a single answer, I'll just accept the first answer I was given.

Answer (score 2):

What 2. means is that $|f(x)-f(y)|=2\,|x-y|$ if both $x$ and $y$ are on the same side of $1/2$. Iterating, we get $|f^n(x)-f^n(y)|=2^n\,|x-y|$ as long as all the iterates are on the same side of $1/2$; $x$ and $y$ are *separated* by a factor of $2^n$ when $f$ is applied $n$ times.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.